# Overrule a native PHP function only within a framework

Tags: php, oop

Is is possible to overrule PHP's native functions? In my case looking for a way to overrule the empty() function only within my (own) framework. This is because of auto generated datamodels which seem to ignore my __get() method and __isset() will not always result in valid result.

Can this be done like we also can register multiple autoloaders and create structures with inherited methods from the OOP principles? I only need this to work in the framework.

Comment: `empty()` is not a function. You can't override it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather write a function yourself that either calls `empty` or does some magic regarding those problematic classes of yours.

Or otherwise fix the classes so they work with `empty`, but I would choose the first. Many PHP functions dont't do exactly what you want, so if you got a framework anyway, I would wrap most of them so you always have the possibility to add your own functionality.

Comment: Well, it's not really my fault that `empty($foo->bar)` doesn't get triggerd by `__get($p)`, is it? 'Those problematic classes' work fine but this is expected behavior (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). See 2nd note.

Comment: I'm not saying it's your fault. Just trying to suggest alternatives. That second note you mention seems to implement the `__isset` magic method. So instead of overriding a core function (and possibly breaking any library you're gonna use in combination with your framework), you could also try that.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I am aware of to redefine functions in PHP (apart from modifying the source code) is with [runkit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.runkit.php) - although there is pretty much *never* a time when this is the right answer to a problem. However, even this probably won't work with `empty()`, because it is a language construct and not a function.

Comment: @BenFransen Sorry, how do you mean "heavy"? I can't lift it, but that has more to do with my hands and the fact that they just refuse to pick up that pesky code, rather than weight... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [override_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) on the [Advanced PHP debugger](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php) to do this.

Comment: neato! I was looking for something like this

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, `empty($foo->bar)` is not triggering `Foo::__get()`, right?  This is technically correct behavior, as `$foo->bar` *does not exist*, so of course it's empty.  You have several options to get the behavior you're looking for, but most of them involve defining your own function or class method which *does* use `Foo::__get()`.  For example:

```
public function isEmpty($prop) {
    $foo = $this->__get($prop);
    return empty($foo);
}
```

Hope that helps.